# Admin menu duplicate errors

Tags: commerce

I'm having a problem with duplicate administration menu bars, is there a way to remove it?
I'm using commerce kickstart 2 and I've uninstalled the commerce kickstart menus and installed Administration menu. The problem was present whenever I don't have commerce kickstart menu enabled.

[image: Admin menu duplicate]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Disable the "Commerce Kickstart menus", the "Toolbar Megamenu" and the "Toolbar" modules.

Later, go to the admin/structure/menu/management and reorder the menu links as shown in the video.

Found the solution with detailed steps here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMoTuHf5WX0

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: edited the comment